# Exclude fields from result in MongoDB monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to exclude some fields from result.
I have code:

```
users = db.select('users');

users.find( {}, { sort: { points:1 }, privateKey:0, publicKey:0}, function(err,data){      
  res.send(data);
});
```

I want to exclude private and public key from results.
Can I do that using monk?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can also do it like this:

```
users.find( {}, { sort: { points:1 }, fields : { privateKey:0, publicKey:0} },
  function(err,data){      
    res.send(data);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 7):

According to documentation first argument in find is filter and second is projection .But you have used sort .  It will not able to interpret .  You are trying to confuse projection with sort .Sorting should be after find and projection.

You can write projection like  `{ field1: <boolean>, field2: <boolean> ... }`

Note :
The find() method always includes the _id field even if the field is not explicitly stated to return in the projection parameter.

```
 users.find({}, { privateKey: 0, publicKey: 0 }).sort({points: 1}).toArray(
           function (err, data) {
                      res.send(data);
             });
```

Comment: this is incorrect, you need to insert the parent/top property "fields" .. like this: { fields: { privateKey: 0 } } to declare that it is a projection. or simply use a string only for the second argument. check the examples in the docs: https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/find.html

Answer (score 2):

For me, I need to use the `.project()` method:

```
const someFunction = async () => {

    const result = await users
        .find({}, { sort: { points: 1 })
        .project({ privateKey: 0, publicKey: 0});

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me for excluding the `_id` field.

```
const courseChapters = await db
        .collection("users")
        .find({}, { projection: { _id: 0 } })
        .toArray();
```

So the example in the question would look something like this.

```
 users.find(
  {},
  { projection: { points: 1, privateKey: 0, publicKey: 0 } },
  function (err, data) {
    res.send(data);
  }
);
```

Check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294613/mongo-find-function-wont-exclude-id) that says you may need the `fields` field instead of `projection` depending upon your driver