# Mongo Find() function won't exclude _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello I can't seem to get the exclude _id to work, here is the code

```
const findLabels = (db, cb) => {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection(documentName);

  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray((err, docs) => {
    // An error occurred we need to return that to the given 
    // callback function
    if (err) {
      return cb(err);
    }

    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)

    return cb(null, docs);
  });
}
```

Here is the output on the console log

```
Found the following records
[ { _id: 5a5ee78cc130e727a3b1fdb6, name: 'Downgradeklajds' },
  { _id: 5a5ee794c130e727a3b1fdb7, Pizel: '00:00:07' } ]
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think the correct way to specify a projection is to use the "fields" or "projection" property, depends on the version of your driver.

```
collection.find({}, {projection:{ _id: 0 }})
```

Read documentation [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find).

Comment: You're awesome, the solution worked! I hope you have a great day and find a lucky 20 dollar bill on the floor!

Comment: @Lee, you just saved me hours of frustration as well. Thanks!!

Comment: @user1791914 Glad it helps.

Comment: For anyone using pymongo use this: `collection.find({}, {'_id': False})`

Answer (score 10):

for newer version simply do:

```
collection.find({}, {_id: 0 })
```

where find {} refers to all (no restrictions) and the next parameter is the projection so 0 or False excludes the _id (same for `{_id: False }` )

Comment: I use Mongo DB Atlas and the best accepted answer [projection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294672/1705829) solution helped, without it did not work.

Comment: Atlas supports many versions of MongoDB, so it's not at all relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `findOne`,

you can try

```
    const posts : Collection= db.collection('posts')
    let document = await posts.findOne({
            path: path
        }, {
            fields: {
                _id: 0
        }
    })
```

In example, I query path(used as _id)