# NodeJs And MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, filter, find

```
      db.getCollection('Leave').find({},{_id:0 , 
      Can_It_Be_carry_forwarded:1})
```

this is working perfectly in the MongoDb Client CMD But not in the Below Code

```
      var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
      var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Chatbot_Project";

      MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
         if (err) throw err;

         var dbo = db.db("Chatbot_Project");
         dbo.collection('Leave').find({}, {Can_It_Be_carry_forwarded:1}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) 
              throw err;

            console.log(result);
            db.close();
         })
       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the find method, you are missing the projection field.
If you want to retrive only the `Can_It_Be_carry_forwarded` field you need the following: `{projection:{Can_It_Be_carry_forwarded:1, _id: 0}}` as the second argument.

Solution from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48294672/4120554

Documentation: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find

Try this:

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
  var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Chatbot_Project";

  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
     if (err) throw err;

     var dbo = db.db("Chatbot_Project");
     dbo.collection('Leave').find({},{projection:{_id: 0, Can_It_Be_carry_forwarded:1}}).toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) 
          throw err;

        console.log(result);
        db.close();
     })
   });
```

Comment: Thank u it Worked perfectly Fine