# MongoDb Projection not filtering return data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Function Declaration:

```
static getUserInDatabase = ( userId ) => {
        const db = getDb();
        return db.collection( process.env.USERSCOLLECTION ).findOne( { _id: ObjectId( userId ) }, { name: 1 } );

    };
```

Function Call

```
exports.getFriend = async ( req, res, next ) => {
    const friend = await User.getUserInDatabase( req.body.friendId.id );
    if ( friend !== null ) {
        res.status( 200 ).send( friend );
    } else {
        res.status( 200 ).send( { message: "Did not find a friend with that ID" } );
    }
};
```

MongoDB User Document

```
{
  _id: 5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226,
  tokens: [],
  friends: [ 5dfa26f46719311869ac1756, 5dfa270c6719311869ac1757 ],
  incomingFriendRequest: [],
  incomingSpaceInvites: [],
  name: 'Account 1',
  email: 'account1@gmail.com',
  password: '$2b$10$OzHulmDup8btvdWw5.XnMetRprlh/m3q6ydgFRkNqmYMtvyuRAlGu',
  spaces: [ 5e16fcbabc23c11124cebf0e, 5e171c544f9bff15aafae505 ],
  tasks: []
}
```

When calling the function, I expect to receive only `{_id: 5dfa24dce9cbc0180fb60226, name: Account 1}`
However, I receive everything in the document.

Am I using this wrong? Everywhere I look do the exact same as me when wanting to filter out the response fields.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongo Find() function won't exclude \_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48294613/mongo-find-function-wont-exclude-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are using [Node.js MongoDB Driver API](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/api/Collection.html#findOne)

Following the documentation the second parameters of `findOne` is the options (not only used for projection). You have to use it like :

```
.findOne({
    _id: ObjectId(userId),
 }, {
  projection: {
     name: 1,
  },
})
```